# Is there any surface of revolution for which none of its parallels are geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, geodesic

I found it in a proposed exercises sheet and I find it very interesting

Is there any surface of revolution for which none of its parallels are geodesics?

What about if $S$ is a surface of revolution made by rotating a plane, closed and simple curve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the parallels of a cone?

Comment: Consider which parallels of the sphere, ellipsoid, and torus are geodesic. What do these all have in common?